# Example of $(L^1)^* \neq L^\infty$ from Exercise 6.12 in Rudin's RCA

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

This is Exercise 6.12 from Rudin's RCA.

Let $\mathscr{M}$ be the collection of all sets $E$ in the unit interval $[0,1]$ such that either $E$ or its complement is at most countable. Let $\mu$ be the counting measure on this $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{M}$. If $g(x)=x$ for $0\le x \le 1$ show that $g$ is not $\mathscr{M}$-measurable,although the mapping 
$$f \mapsto \sum xf(x) = \int fg d\mu$$ makes sense for every $f\in L^1(\mu)$ and defines a bounded linear functional on $L^1(\mu)$. Thus $(L^1)^* \neq L^\infty$ in this situation.

It is easy to prove the assertions. Why does this lead to $(L^1)^* \neq L^\infty$? We have only shown the existence of a bounded linear functional of the form $\int fg d\mu$ where $g \notin L^\infty$. Thus, the canonical map $g \mapsto (f \mapsto \int fg d\mu)$ is not isomorphic, but why is this enough to conclude that $(L^1)^* \neq L^\infty$? Is it not possible that there may be other isomorphism that maps an element of $L^\infty$ to the map $f \mapsto \int fg d\mu$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\int fg \, d\mu = \int x f \, d\mu$ for all $f\in L^1(\mu)$, then necessarily $g(x) = x$. To see this, fix $y \in [0,1]$ and choose 
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x=y, \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}
$$
Then $g(y) = \int f g \, d\mu = \int x f \, d\mu = y$. But $y$ was arbitrary, so $g(x) = x$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.

Comment: But how do we know all duals of $L^1$ must be of the form $f \mapsto \int fg d\mu$? I know this is the case for $\sigma$-finite measures but is it also true for any general measure?

Comment: This was not your question. The question was: "Is it not  possible that there may be other isomorphism that maps an element of $L^\infty$ to the map $f\mapsto \int fg \, d\mu$?". And the above shows that this is not possible for any $g \in L^\infty$.

Comment: But, if you want to show that all duals of $L^1$ are of this form, then you should be able to use the same idea of defining $f(x) = 1_{y}(x)$ and testing your element of the dual $\phi \in (L^1)^\ast$ with $f$, letting you define $g(y):= \langle \phi, 1_y \rangle$. Then, show that for any $f\in L^1$, we have $\langle \phi, f\rangle = \int fg \, d\mu$....

Comment: Thank you that resolves all my questions.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

In fact the existence of another isomorphism is irrelevant. When people say $(L^1)^*=L^\infty$ they're referring to the canonical  isomorphism. And thus the assertion $(L^1)^*\ne L^\infty$ is *not* meant to say that the two are not isomorphic; all that's claimed is that the canonical map from  $L^\infty$ to $(L^1)^*$ is not an isomorphism.

(Similarly, perhaps of more interest: There exists a non-reflexive Banach space $X$ such that $X^{**}$ *is* isometrically isomorphic to $X$: [James tree space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James%27_space))

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3290121/james-tree-space-ish-example-for-l1-l-infty-in-place-of-x-x/3290161#3290161) you can find an example where $(L^1)^*\ne L^\infty$ but the two spaces *are* isometrically isomorphic...