# James-tree-space-ish example for $(L^1)^*=L^\infty$ in place of $X^{**}=X$?

Tags: measure-theory

Is there an example of a measure space such that $(L^1)^*$ *is* isometrically isomorphic to $L^\infty$, although "$(L^1)^*\ne L^\infty$" (meaning as usual that the canonical map is not an isomorphism)?

(See the revision history for my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3289612/example-of-l1-neq-l-infty-from-exercise-6-12-in-rudins-rca) for a very simple and very wrong example.)

Answer (score 1):

A very simple example: $(X,A,\mu)$, where $X=\Bbb  N$, $A$ is the power set, and $\mu(\{1\})=\infty$,  $\mu(\{n\})=1$ for $n\ne 1$.

Then $L^\infty$ is the space of all bounded functions, while $$(L^1)^*=\{f\in L^\infty:f(1)=0\}.$$